# AutoIt: Illegal text at end of statement

Tags: autoit

I'm unable to figure out what it wrong with this

```
Func Hypotenuse($a, $b)
    Return sqrt($a * $a + $b * $b)
EndFunc
```

Error is

```
Func Hypotenuse($a, $b)
Func Hypotenuse($a, $b)^ERROR

Error: Illegal text at end of statement (one statement per line).
```

EDIT: It appears to have been a hidden character

Comment: Can't spot any error in the Hypotenuse function. Can you post the full code?

Comment: Perhaps you have a hidden character in the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copied code from AutoIt forum or some other Invision Power Board driven forum.

If that is correct, you copy the end-of-line HTML-character if you don't pop out the code box. Easiest fix for many lines is to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, copy & paste into Notepad, then copy that and paste back into SciTE.

Answer (score 2):

Well, nothings wrong there :O

This:

```
Func Hypotenuse($a, $b)
    Return sqrt($a * $a + $b * $b)
EndFunc


ConsoleWrite(Hypotenuse(2,2))
```

Works perfect for me? And for you? Whats the rest of the Code?

Answer (score -1):

This sort of thing can happen when you call your function from the incorrect  `If..Then` statement. For example, the code

```
If Hypotenuse(1,1) > 0 Then ConsoleWrite("test" & @CRLF) EndIf
```

gives you an "Illegal text at end of statement" error, whereas the code

```
If Hypotenuse(1,1) > 0 Then ConsoleWrite("test" & @CRLF)
```

or

```
If Hypotenuse(1,1) > 0 Then
   ConsoleWrite("test" & @CRLF)
EndIf
```

works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue when I had an extra ) at the end of the call.

Real code issue:

```
LogProgram("(SM) Selected Image SM: " & $imageList[$smPicName]))
```

Correct:

```
LogProgram("(SM) Selected Image SM: " & $imageList[$smPicName])
```